# Sunspot does not start on the development port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I am trying to run sunspot on the development port (8982).
I run the following command
    $ RAILS_ENV=development rake sunspot:solr:start

Sunspot starts but it does not start on the development port, it starts on port 8983, which is the production port.
I am not using config/sunspot.yml. I have a config/initializers/sunspot.rb file which reads as follows

```
require File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'sunspot', 'rails', 'adapters')
Sunspot::Adapters::InstanceAdapter.register(Sunspot::Rails::Adapters::ActiveRecordInstanceAdapter, ActiveRecord::Base)
Sunspot::Adapters::DataAccessor.register(Sunspot::Rails::Adapters::ActiveRecordDataAccessor, ActiveRecord::Base)

module Sunspot
  HIGHLIGHTS = {
    :elements => ['span'], :attributes => { 'span' => ['class'] }
  }
```

Additionally in config/environments/development.rb I have a line that reads

```
Sunspot.config.solr.url = 'http://localhost:8982/solr'
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I need to start sunspot on Port 8982 ( the development node).

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I believe I'm having a similar problem, which I detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565149/connection-refused-using-sunspot-and-solr-in-rails

Comment: Does it work using a YAML configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/262 to track the resolution of the bug.